# Why do car key remotes not use E2EE?

Tags: wireless, locks, vehicle

### Background

I read [an article](https://www.theverge.com/2016/8/12/12456014/car-key-fob-volkswagen-vulnerability-unlock-hack-crack) about how car keys that remotely open one's car are not secure. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/43053/192118) also talks about different encryption methods being insecure.

The article mentions that common encryption keys were used across many different vehicles.

### Unique end-to-end encryption

Now, I am wondering: *why do manufacturers not just assign **unique** keys for every **single** car-key combination?*

A simple implementation I would imagine is the vehicle and key using a unique mathematic formula to build a code based on time. Now, only keeping the time accurate would need to be assured and I cannot imagine a way of a third party cracking this scheme. *See: the code would never be the same for any second in time* and with a formula complex enough no correlation visible.

#### Why are remote keys insecure?

Car keys still being insecure today leads me to the conclusion that there must be some loophole in my idea.

Comment: What happens if you lose your car key and need to replace it?

Comment: This question has already an answer at [crypto.se]: [Why do key fobs/garage doors openers use rolling codes instead of PGP or SSL encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42712/why-do-key-fobs-garage-doors-openers-use-rolling-codes-instead-of-pgp-or-ssl-enc).

Comment: @MikeScott When you have access to the physical car or key, you can get the encryption "key" / formula.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The consent on that answer is that it is too expensive for manufacturers. I think that that is fair. I will still leave this question open because it is more focused about whether e.g. what I proposed would really be secure.